# A website shows a different IP address from what I have

Tags: gmail, discord, puffin-browser

I live in the Middle East. I tried to log in to my Discord account using a browser called Puffin Browser on my iphone. It said to check my email to verify. 30 seconds later, I got an email that said an attempted login was from California, and it showed a different IP address than mine. How is this possible? It’s obvious this attempt login is me, but how can the IP address change like that? Any reasons why?

Comment: the same thing happens on [Google Chrome](https://serverfault.com/q/662382/343888)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the puffin browser [FAQ](https://www.puffinbrowser.com/help/trouble.php)

> Puffin uses our servers in USA / Singapore to improve the user
>   experience. The side effect is that the websites receive Puffin's
>   servers IP rather than yours. Although Puffin passes your IP to
>   websites via X-Forwarded-For, some websites don't support this
>   standard.

Comment: This means all traffic goes to the US then on to where it is destined - so if you are attempting to access a middle east server - the traffic goes a long way around

Comment: Usually the do it for better compression, that is, faster downloads ("user experience").